# OllyDbg color palette

Tags: ollydbg

How can I change color palette in OllyDbg(Appearance dialog).
There are only 20 colors to choose from and most of those are too bright for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download [OllyDbg version 2](http://www.ollydbg.de/version2.html). It has a section called "customizable colors":

[image: OllyDbg version 2 customizable colors]